# Test case failed in Jest with " expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality"

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I tried to work on basic Jest testing in JavaScript. I went through the docs file and worked accordingly. Everything look good to me but a simple test case is not passing. I have attached the screenshot for the issue along with the code and package.json.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6Kio.png)
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZP6P.png)

```
const functions = {
  add: (num1, num2) => {
    num1 + num2;
  },
};

module.exports = functions;


`//Testing `
const functions = require("./functions");

    test("Add 2 + 2 equal 4", () => {
      expect(functions.add(2, 2)).toBe(4);
    });

Error
expect(received).toBeCloseTo(expected)

Matcher error: received value must be a number

Received has value: undefined
```

Comment: Please put a [mre], **as text**, in the question.

Comment: You do not return anything from the `add` function. You must either add a `return` statement (`return num1 + num2;`) or define the function like this: `add: (num1, num2) => num1 + num2`

Comment: add doesn't return anything...

Comment: That helped, thank you very much.